# Regex: find value based on pattern and constant string in dynamic HTML in C#

Tags: c#, regex

I need assistance building a regex to solve this problem:

I have some HTML from which an Id needs to be extracted. The attributes in the html can move around.

Example 1: need to extract the **gm_5** part of the href

```
<a class="other_class" href=\"10-2-gm_2_0.sub#\">text<a/>
<div class=\"ocq\" id=\"gm_5_0\" a=\"29\" o=\"2000002\">
<span class=\"a\">
<a class=\"static_class\" href=\"10-2-gm_5_0.sub#\" tabindex=\"-1\" o=\"108\" target=\"_blank\">Some Static String</a>
</span></div>
<a class="other_class" href=\"10-2-gm_3_0.sub#\">text<a/>
```

Example 2: need to extract the **in_5** part of the href

```
<a class="other_class" href=\"10-2-gm_2_0.sub#\">text<a/>
<div o=\"2000002\" id=\"in_5_0\" a=\"29\" class=\"ocq\">
<span class=\"a\">
<a o=\"108\" class=\"static_class\" href=\"10-2-in_5_0.sub#\" tabindex=\"-1\" target="_blank">Some Static String</a>
</span>
</div>
<a class="other_class" href=\"10-2-gm_3_0.sub#\">text<a/>
```

Some notes:

1. These snippets are embedded in much larger documents containing many similar  tags, hence why I am mentioning the "Some Static String" text that can **always** be found after the tag
2. As shown, the attributes can move around
3. The "static_class" is always there (though I can't guarantee it's always left of the href)
4. The "Some Static String" is always there and always to the right of the target href
5. I am using C# to extract this Id

Many thanks for you help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<a.*?href="(?:\d+-)+(.*?)_\d\.sub`

This is the expression that works for me.

https://regex101.com/r/DDfehg/1

Comment: Apologies, in the big picture, there are tags before and after the ones I am targeting that create noise, i.e.  tons of similar <a (...) tags. This is why I mention the "Some Static String" that is always contained in the target <a></a>. I will update my question